# Twilio international calling from Austria and Netherlands

Tags: twilio

I am using a Twilio SIP trunk with Avaya IP office and am using Twilio for international calls. I have successful numbers with Germany and Australia for inbound/outbound voice. I enabled permissions in Twilio and configured new numbers for Austria and Netherlands. When I call them using my outbound SIP with Twilio, they work. When our clients try them from those countries, the calls don't even originate in the logs. How can I track down where the issue is?

Comment: I recommend you get in touch with [Twilio support](https://www.twilio.com/help/contact) and let them know about this. They can investigate with carriers if required.

Comment: Thank for the reply. I am going back and forth with them now. They recommended I check that permissions were enabled here: https://www.twilio.com/console/voice/settings/geo-permissions but they were enabled. They also mentioned checking whitelisting of Twilio IPs - https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/sip-trunking/getting-started#whitelist  but I am unable to try this without the network admin's help.

Comment: Cool, hope they get you sorted out!

Comment: Turns out that traffic from Austria and the Netherlands routes through different IPs than our current traffic in Germany and Australia. I had to configure a new SIP trunk to make it work. IP office only allows 5 or 6 ITSP proxy's so a new trunk was necessary. I just made successful calls from Google Voice and our local PRI. Thanks for your comments!

Comment: Glad it's all working now!